# Clearing inbox messages

Tags: discussion, global-inbox

Is there any facility to clear inbox message? If I want to delete some of the messages from inbox, then is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not really an inbox, it's [**notifications** of activity that is relevant to you and hence you might be interested in](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/).

Everything you see in that 'inbox' is a public post somewhere on the Stack Exchange network. So once you've acknowledged that you've seen it (by dropping down the inbox, which clears the red dot), there's nothing more to do.

Comment: +1 for the description. Though I'd say a box for incoming notifications really _is_ an inbox - it's just not the same as an e-mail inbox (which is a type of _mailbox_). Splitting hairs, probably. :)

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no direct way to clean those "messages" because they're not standalone - they represent some real content that exist somewhere else and only linked in the message.

The only way to have messages removed from your Stack Exchange Inbox is to delete the related posts/comments.

For example, you can flag [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919169/how-do-i-fix-this-error-warning-implicit-declaration-of-function-main-menu/9920102#comment12663664_9920102) as "obsolete" or "not constructive" if you want and if moderator will remove it, the related item in your Inbox would be removed as well.

In case of answers to your question (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9992631/447356))  there's not much you can do though.

If you will explain why it bothers you so much to have Inbox items maybe we can come with better answer.

Answer (score 1):

To clear the glowing red dot, just view them. (Click on the glowing dot)

Otherwise, nope--no facility to clear inbox messages. Why would you want that anyway?

Comment: not red dot.. I want to delete some of the messages from my inbox

Comment: @Parag: Why? What's wrong with them? They'll disappear on their own... Though you'll always see them at http://stackexchange.com/users/1359681?tab=inbox . If you want to delete an offensive comment belonging to someone else, flag it. Remember, this inbox isn't like email--you don't have to clean up.

Comment: How can I keep unprocessed items on top of this inbox? Currently I have two processed items above one I still have to react to (and currently cannot meaningfully). I have two open questions that will generate more notifications within the time frame, where I want that third item unprocessed - so it will become the fifth+ item. Without going to "full inbox" I can only see the _four_ latest items, so it risks getting buried before I can come back to it. ... Removing processed items from the inbox would be the intuitive way to handle this. They no longer serve a purpose there.