# How do I clean my inbox?

Tags: support, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clearing inbox messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128253/clearing-inbox-messages)

Someone answered a question

And then I got a notification in my inbox

And then I clicked on it

And then I did not find it useful

And then I downvoted it

And then I saw the answer was deleted

And then I smiled

But my inbox is still spammed :(

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to remove these things from your inbox.  Even if the answer is deleted, the notification will still be there.

Once you have clicked on it, the red notification bubble will disappear and the notification is marked as "read".

The [MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66838/172936) only shows "recent" stories. To see your entire inbox, you can visit your [Stack Exchange profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1395422?tab=inbox).

Comment: bah, humbug >:(

Comment: Can I ask why this bothers you so much?

Comment: i'm crazy, that's why

Comment: Ahh.. ok... (* slowly backs away *)

Comment: you better stay away >:D i'll strike you down with my great Sword of DoenVoet

Comment: The Sword of DoenVoet [works slightly differently on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) ;)

Comment: It is actually much more powerful with the force field of Sarkazm

Comment: Sarkazm has been deprecated since version 6.0.  Please use the more recent `Snarkumber` methods.

Comment: @Lix: I thought Snarkumber was deprecated, too, and replaced with SumOLove?

Comment: SumOLove was discontinued... prepare yourselves... winter is coming...

Comment: Casts *HOLY* on all and leaves